# How does ruby do the + operator?

Tags: ruby, operators, increment, post-increment

Ruby does not support incrementing variables like `variable++`. I saw this behaviour that:

```
2 ++ 4
```

gives `6`. In fact, any number of `+` signs between two variables are treated as one single `+`. How does ruby manage that? And since ruby does that, can it be taken as the reason for the unavailability of the `++` operator?

Comment: `2 +- 4` also works...for some reason

Comment: @MxyL: That's because it is `2 + (-4)` so you get the unary `-` operator (AKA `-@` method).

Comment: 2 +- 4 !! would have understood the working if i had done that ! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This:

```
2 ++ 4
```

is parsed as:

```
2 + (+4)
```

so the second `+` is a unary plus. Adding more pluses just adds more unary `+` operators so:

```
2 ++++++ 4
```

is seen as:

```
2 + (+(+(+(+(+(+4))))))
```

If you provide your `+@` method in `Fixnum`:

```
class Fixnum
  def +@
    puts 'unary +'
    self
  end
end
```

then you can even see it happen:

```
> 2 ++ 4
unary +
 => 6
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the overriding code snippet ? doesnt work for me .

Comment: Are you saying `2 ++ 4` or `2 ++4`? Ruby is sensitive to whitespace. You'll also notice that `+4` won't call `+@`, the parser itself will convert that to just `4` before the method has a chance to be called.

Comment: Which version of Ruby and how are you checking?

Comment: 1.8.7 . Going into irb and using your code up there.

Comment: I don't even have 1.8.7 available anymore, maybe you should use a newer Ruby.

Comment: I'd guess that 1.8.7 is interpreting the `+ 4` as just `4` before anything gets a chance to call the `+@` method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ++ use +=
Example:
a=2
a+=3
puts a

> > 5

Comment: Yes but why does ++ work? Or ++++++++++ for that matter. Note that you could even say `8 +---------- 3` and it's still a valid operation

Comment: += works is known. I just wanted to know the mystery of multiple pluses. :)